# Why won't my div class work?

Tags: html, css

When I execute this code the image pops up but when you hover over nothing happens and the width and heights aren't right. Yes the .cover is in the style and the div is in the body. Any help on why this wont work?

```css
.cover img {
  float: left;
  width: 303px;
  height: 352;
}

.cover img:hover {
  opacity: 45%;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <img src="GhostRecon.png">
  <img src="tomb.jpg" width>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to provide a unit to your height and width, in this case your height is missing `px`, also you have a `width` attribute on your second image that isn't doing anything

Comment: try running your CSS through a CSS linter such as http://csslint.net/.

Answer (score 1):

There was some issues, one being that you didn't give units for your height, and you gave your image a width, but no value, but I fixed it for you.

```
.cover img{
    float: left;
    width: 303px;
    height: 352px;
}

.cover img:hover {
    opacity: 45%;
    color: white
}

<div class="cover">
    <img src="GhostRecon.png">
    <img src="tomb.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can't set the 'color' property of an image, that's why that isn't working. 'opacity' isn't working because it doesn't take a `%` value, instead it takes a value between `1` and `0`.

Try:

```
opacity: .45;
```

Here is your code:

```
.cover img{
  float: left;
  width: 303px;
  height: 352px; // add px here
}

.cover img:hover {
  opacity: .45; // use .45 instead of 45%
  color: white; // missing semicolon, but also this won't work on an image
}

<div class="cover">
    <img src="GhostRecon.png">
    <img src="tomb.jpg"> // I removed 'width' here
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries @Sam - if you're happy with the answer, I'd love it if you could accept it, by clicking the checkmark next to my answer (near the up and down buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to give units to your height and width (`px`). I see you also tried to use `color` on the image, but you should probably be using a filter. You can use filters by `-webkit-filter` and `filter`. You can change an image to grayscale, sepia, increase the saturation, contrast, brightness, and a lot of other things. I also noticed you put a percent value for `opacity`, but opacity uses a value between 0 and 1, the lower, the more transparent. 45% would be .45 instead.

Here's some stuff fixed but I'm not sure which filter you would want on your image so I'll leave that up to you!

```
.cover img {
  float: left;
  width: 303px;
  height: 352px; //Don't forget px here
}

.cover img:hover {
  opacity: .45; //Changed from % to decimal
  //here's where you would put the filter
}
<div class="cover">
  <img src="GhostRecon.png">
  <img src="tomb.jpg"> //width not necessary here
</div>
```